# Errno 98: Address already in use - Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

This question has been asked before but none of the answers was helpful in my case. The problem seems very simple. I am running a TCP server on an raspberry pi and try to connect to it from another machine. I have a custom class receiver that pipes sensor data to this script.

When I close the program running on the other machine (the socket is 'shutdown(2)'d and then 'close()'d), I cannot reconnect to that same port anymore. I tried to alternate between two sockets (1180 and 1181) but this did not work. When I connect over a port once, it is gone forever until I restart the TCP server. I tried restarting the script (with executl()) but that did not resolve my problem. I am telling the socket that it should re-use addresses but to no avail.

What I could do is use more ports but that would require opening more ports on the RPi which I would like to avoid (there must be another way to solve this).

```
import socket
from receiver import receiver
import pickle
import time
import os
import sys

TCP_IP = ''
TCP_PORT = 1180
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

print 'Script started'

while(1):
    try:
            print 'While begin'
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            print 'Socket created'
            s.settimeout(5)
            print 'Trying to bind'
            s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
            print 'bound to', (TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)
            s.listen(1)
            print 'listening for connection'

            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print 'accepted incoming connection'
            s.settimeout(5)
            r = receiver()
            print 'Connection address:', addr
            for cur in r:
                 #print "sending data:", cur
                 print len(cur.tostring())
                 conn.send(cur.tostring())  # echo
    except Exception as e:
            r.running = False
            print e
            if TCP_PORT == 1181:
                    TCP_PORT = 1180
            else:
                    TCP_PORT = 1181
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'sleeping 1sec'
```

Comment: Why do you need to keep switching ports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server socket is still in use, so you cannot open more than one server socket for each port. But why should one. Just reuse the same socket for all connections (that's what server sockets made for):

```
import socket
from receiver import receiver
import logging

TCP_IP = ''
TCP_PORT = 1180
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

print 'Script started'
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
print 'Trying to bind'
server.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print 'bound to', (TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)
server.listen(1)
print 'listening for connection'

while True:
    try:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print 'accepted incoming connection'
        print 'Connection address:', addr
        for cur in receiver():
            data = cur.tostring()
            #print "sending data:", cur
            print len(data)
            conn.sendall(data)  # echo
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("processing request")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. I feel stupid now.